# How to show full-length numbers(5000 instead of 5K) in google charts?

Tags: javascript, charts

displayExactValues option doesn't work for me and formatter as well, looks like I'm on the wrong path. Any help? Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?ext.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div_9reg"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCurveTypes);
    function drawCurveTypes(){

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'test');
        data.addColumn('number', 'products');
        data.addRows([
            ['2', 12721],
            ['4', 1621],
            ['5', 12221],
            ['6', 12231],
            ['7', 12221],
        ]);

        var options = {
            height: 400,
            height: 600,
        };
        var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div_9reg'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the format to the `var options`.

Change your `options` the following way:

```
    var options = {
        height: 400,
        height: 600,
        axes: {
          y: { 
            all: {
              format: {
                pattern: 'decimal'
              }
            } 
          }
        }
    };
```

[Reference.](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes)

You can control the formatting of label numbers with `hAxis.format` and `vAxis.format`. For instance, `{hAxis: { format:'#,###%'} }` displays the values "1,000%", "750%", and "50%" for values 10, 7.5, and 0.5. You can also supply any of the following presets:

- `{format: 'none'}`: displays numbers with no formatting (e.g.,
  8000000)
- `{format: 'decimal'}`: displays numbers with thousands
  separators (e.g., 8,000,000)
- `{format: 'scientific'}`: displays
  numbers in scientific notation (e.g., 8e6)
- `{format: 'currency'}`:
  displays numbers in the local currency (e.g., $8,000,000.00)
- `{format: 'percent'}`: displays numbers as percentages (e.g.,
  800,000,000%)
- `{format: 'short'}`: displays abbreviated numbers
  (e.g., 8M)
- `{format: 'long'}`: displays numbers as full words (e.g.,
  8 million)

Comment: I have deleted the redundant brackets, try one more time

Comment: And also check the reference link :)

Comment: notice that I have a 'Material Design Line' and hAxis is for the old one, axes: {y:{}} is the new format

Comment: That's fine. Corrected to the `Material Design Line`

Comment: You also have double definition off `height` parameter

Answer (score 0):

problem solved!

```
var options = {
            height: 400,
            height: 600,
            axes: {
                y: {
                    all: {
                        format: {
                            pattern: 'decimal'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        };
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought you'd have to define the format within the axes setting. How did you come across this? through reference (link?) or trial & error? I've been following that's all.